# how to add text box/shape around each cell in the selection?

Tags: excel, vba, textbox

Is there a VBA code to add textboxes around each cell in the selection. textboxes should be exactly the size of the cell(similar to borders)?

Comment: Why not just use the cell?

Comment: sorry I didn't get you??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `.AddTextbox` method. Loop through the cells in your selection, and use the cell's dimensional properties to set the dimensions of your textbox.

```
Sub cellsToTextbox()

    Dim cel As Range

    For Each cel In Selection
        cel.Worksheet.Shapes.AddTextbox 1, cel.Left, cel.Top, cel.Width, cel.Height
    Next cel

End Sub
```

---

## Modifying Textbox Properties

If you wanted to change any of the textbox properties, I would do it while you are creating the textbox itself. My preferred method would be to wrap the entire `.AddTextbox()` method into a `With` statement, and change the individual properties there.

Here's an example changing the `VerticalAnchor` property *(I also moved your request to change the column size here from [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53756994/how-to-add-text-box-shape-around-each-cell-in-the-selection/53757104?noredirect=1#comment94482758_53757104) to this example)*:

```
Sub cellsToTextbox()

    Dim cel As Range

    For Each cel In Selection
        With cel.Worksheet.Shapes.AddTextbox(1, cel.Left, cel.Top, _
                        cel.Resize(ColumnSize:=3).Width, cel.Height)

            .TextFrame2.VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle

        End With
    Next cel

End Sub
```

Comment: Just a follow up question. What is the the function of "Parent"  here. if i remove this, it doesn't work..

Comment: Parent returns the parent of `cel`. Since `cel` is a range object, it's parent will be a worksheet object. So, `Parent` is just referencing the worksheet that `cel` is in. If you were to remove Parent, you would also have to remove `cel` before it - which means that `Shapes.AddTextbox` will now reference the `ActiveSheet` implicitly.

Comment: FYI, a range also has a `Worksheet` property, so this could also be written, perhaps clearer, as `cel.Worksheet.Shapes ...`

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs Need a small tweak to this code. I tried using resize() method, but couldn't get the desired result..  
rather than width of one cell, I want to have 3 cells with (unequal cell with). eg  if in the above loop cel = range("A1"),  then I need the width to be range("A1:C1").  is it possible? i.e. placing the textbox accross 3 cells..

Comment: @Rapto - How did you use `Resize()`? Because it should work. A common mistake is someone using `0` in either the column or row because they aren't resizing it - but you are actually saying you want a column/row size of `0` which isn't possible. Just change the `cel.Width` to `cel.Resize(ColumnSize:=3).Width`.

Comment: Yeah I used with 0 for row. my bad... Thanks a lot. the code works fine..